# '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: python, mysql, macos, pip, ssl-certificate

**First Issue:**

I am using a MackBook Pro to run a python3 program in PyCharm that connects to MySQL ,when I run the program I receive

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql
```

for line 1 which is

```
import mysql.connector
```

**What i have tried:**

I tried to install mysql using `pip`

```
pip3 install mysql-connector-python
```

**new issue:**

while executing

```
pip install mysql-connector-python
```

received:

```
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/mysql-connector-python/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/mysql-connector-python/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)'))) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mysql-connector-python (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for mysql-connector-python
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1076)'))) - skipping"
```